# recvfrom() timeout with alarm()

Tags: linux, posix, signals, alarm

I'm debugging the following code:

```
signal(SIGALRM, testt);                                                  
alarm(1);                                                                
result = recvfrom( listening_socket, buf, maxlen, 0, &from, &fromlen );  
printf("stoped\n");
```

As described by `man 3 siginterrupt` the alarm should interrupt the system call, but in my case it doesn't. Alarm handler is invoked, but `recvfrom` is not interrupted.

> However, when a new signal handler is specified with the signal(2) function, the system call is interrupted by default.

If I add `siginterrupt(SIGALRM, 1);` after setting the alarm handler then `recvfrom` is interrupted as expected.

What am I missing? What's wrong with my code?

NOTES: Replacing `signal` with `sigaction` is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Note that `siginterrupt(3)` is marked obsolete in POSIX.1-2008.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `siginterrupt(3)` manpage was incorrect ([version 3.33](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/changelog.html#release_3.33) of the Linux manpage set corrects the error).  The default behavior of glibc's `signal` is to establish a signal that does *not* interrupt system calls.  You can see this for yourself with `strace`:

```
void handler(int unused) {}
int main(void)
{
  signal(SIGALRM, handler);
}
```

⟶

```
$ strace -e trace=rt_sigaction ./a.out
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, 
             {0x4005b4, [ALRM], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7fe732d3d490}, 
             {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
```

Note the SA_RESTART in there.  You can either keep doing what you're doing -- call `siginterrupt(SIGALRM, 1)` after establishing the handler -- or you can switch to using `sigaction`, which will let you set the flags the way you want in the first place.  You said you didn't want to do that (why?) but nonetheless that is what I would recommend.

Comment: TIL strace -e trace=rt_sigaction. It is not my code that establishes the handler.

Comment: @Zack: the manpage isn't wrong, just misquoted. The full quote is: `If the flag argument is false (0), then system calls will be restarted if interrupted by the specified  signal sig.  This is the default behavior in Linux.  However, when a new signal handler is specified with the signal(2) function, the system call is interrupted by default.`

Comment: @ninjalj: I think I'm too tired, why is the first sentence relevant to `signal()`?

Comment: @Alexandru: it's the second sentence: `This is the default behavior in Linux.` i.e. glibc's `signal()` by default sets SA_RESTART. Humm, now that you say it, the third sentence is wrong.

Comment: @ninjalj It is the last sentence of that quote that is wrong.  The `signal(2)` manpage has several paragraphs explaining that the system call is *not* interrupted (by default, in glibc 2, etc.)

Comment: @Zack: yes, I just noticed it, see my previous comment. Somehow I missparsed that sentence as "However, blah blah the other flag value is specified blah blah syscall interrupted blah blah." :)

Comment: The man page is talking about signal(2), i.e. the signal system call, which is deprecated.  If you call glibc's signal(), it actually uses the sigaction system call.  See http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/signal.2.html Portability section for further information.

Comment: The manpage is no longer wrong: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/online/pages/man3/siginterrupt.3.html http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/changelog.html#release_3.33