# recvfrom not returning -1 after signal

Tags: c, sockets, icmp, raw-sockets

I am writing a ping program using raw sockets but recvfrom is not returning -1 with EINTR even though a SIGALRM is being handled.This SIGALRM is produced by my alarm(1).I want
recvfrom to return so that i can decide that the packet has indeed been lost.

```
#include "libsock"
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>

double total=0, max=0, min=10000000;
int totalpackets=0, packetslost=0;
int recieved=0;

void handler2()
{
  printf("host unreachable\n");
}

unsigned short 
csum (unsigned short *buf, int nwords)
{
  unsigned long sum;
  for (sum = 0; nwords > 0; nwords--)
    sum += *buf++;
  sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
  sum += (sum >> 16);
  return ~sum;
}

void 
handler()
{
  printf("\n");
  printf("--------------PINGING STATISTICS----------------\n");
  printf("AVG:%f MAX:%f MIN:%f TOTAL PACKETS:%d PACKETS LOST:%d SUCCESS PERCENTAGE:%f\n\n",total/(totalpackets-packetslost),max,min,totalpackets,packetslost,((double)(totalpackets-packetslost)/(double)totalpackets)*100);
  exit(0);
}

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf ("need destination for tracert\n");
    exit (0);
  }
  int sfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
  char buf[4096] = { 0 };

  int one = 1;
  const int *val = &one;
  if (setsockopt (sfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof (one)) < 0)
    printf ("Cannot set HDRINCL!\n");

  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  struct ip* ip_hdr=(struct ip*)buf;
  addr.sin_port = htons (7);
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  inet_pton (AF_INET, argv[1], &(addr.sin_addr));

  ip_hdr->ip_hl = 5;
  ip_hdr->ip_v = 4;
  ip_hdr->ip_tos = 0;
  ip_hdr->ip_len = 20 + 8 + 64;
  ip_hdr->ip_id =0;
  ip_hdr->ip_off = 64;
  ip_hdr->ip_ttl = 64;
  ip_hdr->ip_p = IPPROTO_ICMP;
  inet_pton (AF_INET, "172.30.104.59", &(ip_hdr->ip_src));
  inet_pton (AF_INET, argv[1], &(ip_hdr->ip_dst));
  ip_hdr->ip_sum = csum ((unsigned short *) buf, 4);

  struct icmphdr *icmphd = (struct icmphdr *) (buf+20);
  icmphd->type = ICMP_ECHO;
  icmphd->code = 0;
  icmphd->checksum = 0;
  icmphd->un.echo.id = 0;
  icmphd->un.echo.sequence =1;

  memset(buf+28,'a',64);
  icmphd->checksum = csum ((unsigned short *) (buf+20), 36);
  signal(SIGINT,handler);
  struct timeval tv1,tv2;  

  printf("Pinging %s with 64 bytes of data.\n\n",argv[1]);

  while(1)
  {
    recieved=0;     
    totalpackets++;
    sendto (sfd, buf,20+ 8+64, 0, SA & addr, sizeof addr);
    char buff[4096] = { 0 };
    struct sockaddr_in addr2;
    socklen_t len = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);
    signal(SIGALRM,handler2);
    gettimeofday(&tv1,NULL);
    alarm(1);
    int x=recvfrom (sfd, buff, 20+8+64, 0, SA & addr2, &len);
    gettimeofday(&tv2,NULL);
    double   d=(double)(tv2.tv_sec-tv1.tv_sec)*1000+((double)(tv2.tv_usec-tv1.tv_usec))/1000;

    if(x>0) {
      struct icmphdr *icmphd2 = (struct icmphdr *) (buff + 20);
      printf ("Reached destination:%s\tTime elapsed:%f ms\n\n",
          inet_ntoa (addr2.sin_addr),d);
      total+=d;
      if(d>max)
        max=d;
      if(d<min)
        min=d;
    } else {
      printf("Packet lost\n");   
      packetslost++;
    }

    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

libsock contains headers and SA=(struct sockaddr*)

Is SIGALRM different from other signals, I have not set SA_RESTART..

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered just setting a socket timeout?

Comment: @nneonneo thanks for that,didnt know about sock timeout before,my problem is resolved but i am still wondering why recvfrom is not working like i think it should.

Comment: 1) a signal handler should have the signature `void handler(int signum)` 2) Don't use printf() in a signal handler, it is non-reentrant.

Comment: why couldn't you use `printf` in a signal handler? non-reentrant means that the signal is masked during the call.

Comment: @EdouardThiel: see `man 7 signal`

Comment: The signal could arrive while printf is inside malloc, to (re-)allocate its buffer. Or just updating its pointers inside this buffer.

Comment: ok `printf` is not a safe function in the POSIX sense, but it is not forbidden either to call it. Any example or FAQ on it, I'm interested to know more.

Comment: @EdouardThiel: it's tough to make it fail: you have to trigger the signal right while the "outer" `printf` is in the middle of some sensitive operation.  You then wind up in the same re-entrancy situation as with any other thread-based or interrupt-driven multiprocessing system.  The author of the `printf` inner workings can try to minimize the window for corruption (I did in mine) but there are some things it just doesn't seem worth protecting against.

Comment: possible duplicate of [recvfrom() timeout with alarm()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929309/recvfrom-timeout-with-alarm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`signal`'s exact behaviour is system-dependent. From [`man 2 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html):

> The BSD semantics are equivalent to calling `sigaction(2)` with the following
>          flags:
>
> ```
> sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
> ```
>
> The situation on Linux is as follows:
>
> ...
>
> By default, in glibc 2 and later, the `signal()` wrapper function does not
>            invoke the kernel system call.  **Instead, it calls sigaction(2) using
>            flags that supply BSD semantics.**

(emphasis mine)

Thus, by default, on Linux and BSD systems, `signal` will set `SA_RESTART`, which will automatically restart your system call so that it never reports `EINTR`.

You need to use `sigaction` to get precise control over the flags:

```
struct sigaction sact = {
    .sa_handler = handle_sigalrm,
    .sa_flags = 0,
};
sigaction(SIGALRM, &sact, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of using "plain" `signal` is to a large extent up to the OS.  Assuming POSIX conformance, you should use `sigaction` instead.  See [What is the difference between sigaction and signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/what-is-the-difference-between-sigaction-and-signal) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `signal` because it is non portable. Instead, use `sigaction`.

With the option `SA_RESTART`, the blocking call will be silently resumed after the signal is caught.
Without `SA_RESTART`, the blocking call stops, returns -1 and set `errno` to `EINTR`.

Here is a function `mysignal`, which you can use to replace your `signal` call with `options` set to 0:

```
int mysignal (int sig, void (*func)(int), int options) {
  int r; 
  struct sigaction act; 

  act.sa_handler = func; 
  act.sa_flags = options; 
  sigemptyset (&act.sa_mask); 

  r = sigaction (sig, &act, NULL); 
  if (r < 0) perror (__func__); 
  return r;
}
```